# Unable to retrieve Profile picture of user from Azure Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Iam unable to retrieve user profile picture from the dot net code.
I tried to print the Height of the picture. Iam getting
"Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Pfb the Program.cs file:

```
class Program
{

    private static GraphServiceClient _graphClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = LoadAppSetting();
        if (config == null)
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid appsettings.json");
            return;
        }

        var client = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config);

        var graphRequest = client.Users.Request();

        var results = graphRequest.GetAsync().Result;
        
        foreach(var user in results)
        {
            //Console.Write(user.Id + ": " + user.DisplayName);
            ProfilePhoto pro = user.Photo;
            Console.Write(pro.Height);
            


            /* DataServiceStreamResponse photo =  user.ThumbnailPhoto.DownloadAsync();
            using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())
            {

            }*/
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nGraph Request:");
        Console.WriteLine(graphRequest.GetHttpRequestMessage().RequestUri);

    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSetting()
    {
       
        try
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .Build();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationId"]) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationSecret"]) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["redirectUri"]) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["tenantId"]))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return config;   


        }
        catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthorizationProvider(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        var clientId = config["applicationId"];
        var clientSecret = config["applicationSecret"];
        var redirectUri = config["redirectUri"];
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{config["tenantId"]}/v2.0";

        List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
        scopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        //var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(clientId, authority, redirectUri, new ClientCredential(clientSecret), null, null);

     
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        return new MsalAuthenticationProvider(cca, scopes.ToArray());
    }

    private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        var authenticationProvider = CreateAuthorizationProvider(config);
        _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
        return _graphClient;

            }
}
```

}

Pfb the screenshot of permission that the user and application hold.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChCuJ.png)

Also Iam able to retrieve the Profile picture via postman but not via Dot net. Pfb the screenshot from postman:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ARt.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks like for few of the user ,profile photo is not updated (its null), you can check if there is profile is null? I recommend you to check in [graph-explore](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).